# How to know the distinct namespaces in a database in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a database in MarkLogic server. The database has many collections. Some of these collections have a namespace and some have different namespace. What is the query to know the distinct namespaces? My goal is to build a search application that would allow users to use a search bar and have the documents returned from the most relevant collections. Since all the collections have different xml structure I also want to customize the display of the documents base on the collection and search.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're seeking to do. If I understand correctly, you want a list of all permutations of document collection and namespace?

Comment: Are you trying to find a distinct list of all the collections, or a distinct list of namespaces found in the documents loaded in the database? From your description it is not clear whether namespaces happen to be used for the collection names, or if not what collections have to do with namespaces of nodes. If you need to parse the collection names, it would help if you provided some example collection names and an idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

However you question is not clear to me but if you want to get all unique namespace from your DB you may run:

```
fn:distinct-values(//namespace-uri())
```

and if you want to get all unique collection from DB (on collection lexion of the DB):

```
cts:collections()
```

and if you want to perform search on particular collection only:

in search:search use:

```
<additional-query>{cts:collection-query('collectionName')}</additional-query>
```

in cts:search use:

```
cts:collection-query(("reports", "analysis")))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the list of unique collections in a database is to use the [App Services Search API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api). You can specify a collection constraint in the search options which will return the unique collections. The example below specifies a collection constraint without a prefix, then returns a list of the facet values with the number of documents counted for each collection.

```
(: insert test documents here :)
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $i in 0 to 5
  let $collection := "https://example.com/" || $i
  for $j in 0 to $i
    return xdmp:document-insert("/example-doc/" || $i || "-" || $j, <example/>, (), $collection);

(: Use search API to get collections as a facet :)
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = 
  "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

(: build a collection constraint facet :)
let $options := 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="collections">
      <collection prefix="" facet="true" />
    </constraint>
  </options>

(: return facets ordered by the number of documents in each collection :)
let $facets := search:search("", $options)/search:facet/search:facet-value
for $facet in $facets
   order by $facet/@count descending
   return (element collection {($facet/@name, $facet/@count)})
```

Returning:

```
<collection name="https://example.com/5" count="6"/>
<collection name="https://example.com/4" count="5"/>
<collection name="https://example.com/3" count="4"/>
<collection name="https://example.com/2" count="3"/>
<collection name="https://example.com/1" count="2"/>
<collection name="https://example.com/0" count="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have seen most typically with applications built on MarkLogic is that they either have a single search ui for all document types, or separate search ui for each document type. You can always to full-text search across any document type, and you can define and show facets regardless if they apply to all or only a subset of the documents. Collection name could be a facet for instance, but you could also have a facet called Keyword that only applies to two of the collections, and another facet called Company that applies to three other ones.

In short, think of what end users functionality you'd like to provide first, and think how to technically implement that as second step. I doubt knowing the namespaces truly matters to the search ui, and likely only matters on index level.

HTH!